# How to get multiple Taxonomies not All Taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries, multi-taxonomy-query

I am building a movie site, here is the codes to get the taxonomies

```
function display_post_taxonomies( $content ) {

    if( is_single() ) {

        $args = array( 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false );

        $output = 'objects';

        $operator = 'and';

        $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator );

        if( $taxonomies ) {

            $content .= '';

            foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {

                $args = array(
                                'orderby'               => 'name',
                                'echo'                  => false,
                                'taxonomy'              => $taxonomy->name,
                                'title_li'              => '' . __( $taxonomy->labels->name, 'your-themes-text-domain' ) . '',
                                'show_option_none'      => __( 'No ' . $taxonomy->labels->name, 'your-themes-text-domain' )
                            );

                $content .= '' . wp_list_categories( $args ) . '';

            }

            $content .= '';

        }

    }

    return $content;

}
```

The first `$args` is generic to display all not built in taxonomies, but I want to exclude couple of taxonomies but I couldn't
If I want to show just one taxonomy I'll use this code

```
$args = array( 'name' => 'actors');
```

So I've tried the following codes but it didn't work

```
$args = array( 
 'name' => array( 'actors', 'directors', 'musicians' )
);
```

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is in the `if ( $taxonomies )` statement, I believe you want `if ( is_taxonomy( $taxonomy ); )` see [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_taxonomy) for further usages.

I'm not at home so I can't test this, but I think the option you present should work, as mentioned [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies).

```
$args = array( 
 'name' => array( 'actors', 'directors', 'musicians' )
);
```

And I think you should also remove the `.` from `$content .= '';` making it `$content = '';`, this error repeats itself 3x.

I would also like to know, when you use the code `$args = array( 'name' => 'actors');` does the code perform as intended?